# In Copula, pseudo-observation used with kendall tau, but not with Maximum likelihood, Why?

Tags: copula

This is not a coding question! I am confused about using pseudo-observation with some functions but not with MLE in copula model. That is, in `copula` package, the authors wrote that,

```
## A Gumbel copula
    set.seed(7) # for reproducibility
    gumbel.cop <- gumbelCopula(3, dim=2)
    x <- rCopula(n, gumbel.cop) # "true" observations (simulated)
    u <- pobs(x)                # pseudo-observations
    ## Inverting Kendall's tau
    fit.tau <- fitCopula(gumbelCopula(), u, method="itau")
    fit.tau
```

here the author used pseudo-observations with inversion Kendall's tau, the same for log likelihood function. However, the author wrote this for MLE,

```
## Maximum likelihood -- use 'x', not 'u' ! --
    fit.ml <- fitCopula(gumbelCopula(), x, method="ml")
    summary(fit.ml) # now prints a bit more than simple 'fit.ml'
    ## ... and what's the log likelihood (in two different ways):
    (ll. <- logLik(fit.ml))
    stopifnot(all.equal(as.numeric(ll.),
                loglikCopula(coef(fit.ml), u=x, copula=gumbel.cop)))
```

So, why do we need to use pseudo-observation for inversion Kendall's tau and log likelihood functions but we cannot do that for MLE? any idea please?

Comment: I think that because, MLE, need a full estimation (margins and copula parameters). Hence, you cannot use pseudo observation.